# AssertionError : UserSerializser()

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

```
class DjangoRestFrameworkUsageApiTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = UserFactory(first_name='Biola', last_name='Oyeniyi',
                                email='b_oye@example.com', id=1)
        self.booking = BookingFactory(user=self.user, order='ABCDEFGHIJKL')
        WalletTransactionFactory(booking=self.booking,
                                 wallet=self.user.wallet, total=20000)
        self.patch = patch('tuteria_application_test.users.views.UserSerializer')
        self.mock = self.patch.start()
        self.mock.return_value = UserSerializer(UserFactory.get_user(self.user))

    def test_api_view_get_request_returns_valid_response(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.reverse('users:the_api', self.user.pk))
        self.mock.assert_called_once_with(self.user)
        data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        self.assertEqual(data, {
            'first_name': 'First name',
            'last_name': 'Last Name',
            'booking_order': ['ABCDEFGHIJKL'],
            'transaction_total': '1000'
        })
```

### serializer.py

UserSerializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = '__all__'
```

### views.py

```
class UserApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = authentication.TokenAuthentication ###Am assuming you're authenticating via a token

    def get(self, request):
        """
        Get user based on username.
        Am getting only the username since that's the only field used above.
        :param request:
        :param format:
        :return:
        """
        details = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(details)
        return Response(serializer.data  )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Create a new user instance
        :param request:
        :param format:
        :return:
        """
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I have the above test class am carrying out.

When i run the above test case, i get the result below which fails all the time.

```
AssertionError : Expected call:UserSerializer(<User: user-3>)

ActualCall : UserSerializer(<QuerySet [<User: user-3>]>)
```

Now, how do i convert it to a UserSerializer object instead of the QuerySet object?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your UserFactory.get_user method is returning querysets instead of model instances. Try changing

`self.mock.return_value = UserSerializer(UserFactory.get_user(self.user))`

to

`self.mock.return_value = UserSerializer(UserFactory.get_user(self.user).first())`

This will serialize the first object in the queryset instead of the whole queryset.